# Apache Kafka Streams Interactive Queries - How to create a store where the value is an entity and not an aggregation

Tags: apache-kafka, event-sourcing, apache-kafka-streams

I have a topic which receives events with the following info:

key -> `orderId` (Integer)

value -> `{"orderId" : aaa, "productId" : xxx, "userId" : yyy, "state" : "zzz"}` (JSON with the whole info of the order)

I want to implement a interactive query to get the full order information by orderId. The idea is be able to get the current state of an order from a materialized view (the Kafka Streams store).

First I create the KStream of the topic:

`KStream<Integer, JsonNode> stream = kStreamBuilder.stream(integerSerde, jsonSerde, STREAMING_TOPIC);`

Then I create a `KTable` to assign it to a store. The problem is that apparently I can only create stores where the value is an aggregation, for instance: `stream.groupByKey().count("myStore");`

The store I need should have the whole order information, not an aggregation. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the topic directly as a `KTable`, too:

```
KTable<Integer, JsonNode> stream = kStreamBuilder.table(integerSerde, jsonSerde, STREAMING_TOPIC, "store-name-for-IQ");
```

This FAQ might also help: http://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/faq.html#how-can-i-convert-a-kstream-to-a-ktable-without-an-aggregation-step

Comment: Hi Matthias, this is almost what I need, for simplicity I had omitted a step: after I create `stream` there is a filter operation to rule out some of the orders. That is to say, I have to create the `KTable` from a `KStream`, not directly from the topic. From the linked info I guess I would have to use the dummy aggregation right?

Comment: There's something else. I used the dummy aggregation: `.groupByKey().reduce( (val1, val2) -> val2, "OrdersStore");` The problem is that there is a serialization error. How can I specify the value serialization as JSON? `props.put(StreamsConfig.VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, XXXX);`

Comment: Fixed it using a custom Serde: `props.put(StreamsConfig.VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerde.class.getName());` ```public class JsonSerde implements Serde<JsonNode>{

    private Serializer<JsonNode> serializer;
    private Deserializer<JsonNode> deserializer; ...```